# How to include an apostrophe (') in a Whoosh query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, whoosh

How can I include an apostrophe (') in a Whoosh query? For example (**that's**):

```
tws_fileName.tws_query_index( 'that's' )
```

because the query mentioned above does not work, neither does the following

```
tws_fileName.tws_query_index( "that's" )
```

Comment: maybe `"'"` or `'\''`

Comment: What is `tws_query_index`? I can't find that function in the [documentation](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @Andres unfortunately both don't work.

Comment: @Barmar honestly, I'm not sure what it exactly means, but I think it's the format for searching the index.

Comment: What is the class of `tws_fileName`?

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this by default because all punctuation is stripped from the index by the `RegexTokenizer` in the `StandardAnalyzer`.`"that's all, folks!"` is indexed as `[that,s,all,folks]`

You could circumvent this either by:

1. Using a `KEYWORD` instead of `TEXT` field, because it doesn't use the `RegexTokenizer`, but you wouldn't be able to do phrase searches on a keyword field.
2. Using a `TEXT` field with the `StandardAnalyzer` and a custom `RegexTokenizer` regular expression. In the example below, the modified regular expression accepts apostrophes as valid parts of a token.

```
    from whoosh import fields, analysis

    myanalyzer = analysis.StandardAnalyzer(expression=r'[\w\']+(\.?\w+)*')
    schema = fields.Schema(myfield=fields.TEXT(analyzer=myanalyzer))
```

Any apostrophes in `myfield` will now be preserved with the token: `[that's, all, folks]`. If you submit your query as `"that's"` or `'that\'s'`, you will get a match. However, a search for `"that"` will no longer find this document because there is no such token.